# Is there an app for easily switching between screens?

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I watch quite a bit of TV / movies on an HDMi monitor which I hook up to my laptop. When I used windows, there was a shortcut Fn + F2 which brought up screen configurations quickly and I could just click on the 'second screen only' option. In Ubuntu, this short-cut works but it just cycles through the different possible configurations, of which the one I want is the 4th so that's a bit annoying. I know this can be done in settings, but this takes longer I than I really want it to. Is there by any chance an app which provides some sort of user interface which would be equivalent of what's found in windows (picture below)?

[Windows screen options](http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image_thumb2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While as of right now there's no simple menu for that, one can bind a shortcut to open the display settings.

To do so ,

1. go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom.
2. Press <kbd>+</kbd> (plus) button to create new shortcut. You will see a popup asking for Name and Command.
3. Name the new shortcut and set `unity-control-center display` as the command. Click ok
4. When the popup exits, you will see a new entry with the name you set, the keybinding (on the right) will say *Disabled* . Click on the word *Disabled* and when it prompts, press the keybinding you want to use for this shortcut. Personally I've set mine to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

Once the shortcut has been set, it will be ready to use.